# Disable the ping in ubuntu docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, ubuntu-22.04, icmp

I am trying to stop my docker container (running ubuntu 22.04) from replying to ping. Currently, i am trying with these 2 methods:

1. `sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1`. I am only able run this command from inside the container and only if i include the **--privileged** parameter for it to work: `docker run -it --privileged --name container_name image_name`. This does the job but the change is not persistent, meaning if i save the changes to another image with `docker commit running_container_name image_to_be_created_name` and start that image again with docker run, the value of icmp_echo_ignore_all will be **0**.
2. add this line `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1` to the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file then run `sysctl -p` to which i get this error: "sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all : No such file or directory".
   When i try to change the value of icmp_echo_ignore_all (which exists contrary to what the error says) to **1**, manually or by running `echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`
   , i get this error: "bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all: Read-only file system"

I added the command from no.1 in the Dockerfile but is has no effect.

Are there any other ways to disable the ping and preferably the change to be persistent? Are there any commands that i can add to the Dockerfile that will do this thing?

If it helps, i am running this container in AWS ECS using a Fargate launch type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

To disable ping for a container that is using Fargate launch type, when creating the task definition, choose **Create task definition with JSON** and include this in your task definition json:

```
"systemControls": [
                {
                    "namespace": "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all",
                    "value": "1"
                }]
```

Answer (score 1):

The sorts of changes you're describing are *kernel* settings; there's no way to make them "persistent" in a container image. Running `docker commit ...` isn't effective because changing a `sysctl` setting doesn't change any files on disk; there's nothing for Docker to save (and you shouldn't be using `docker commit` in general; you want to use a Dockerfile to build your images so that you have a manageable, repeatable process).

On the other hand, as long as you can ensure that your container runs with appropriate privileges (e.g., `docker run --privileged`), you could configure things so that the commands will be applied automatically when the container starts up.

You could an an [`ENTRYPOINT` script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to your image; this script is run at startup and receives the value of `CMD` as its arguments. If you have an ENTRYPOINT script that looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
exec "$@"
```

And in your Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["my-application"]
```

Then whenever you start the container (`docker run --privileged mycontainer`), it will run the `sysctl` command before running your application.

Comment: I wrote a python script that did exactly what you are describing along with other tasks. The script would throw an error when i would run the container without the --privileged parameter. I have no problems to get this working when running the docker conatiner locally. The issue is i cannot run the container in privileged mode in Fargate as per official AWS documentation: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/fargate-security-considerations.html). That is why i tried to do a persistent change to the container locally and save the changes in a new image.

Comment: "The script would throw an error when i would run the container without the --privileged parameter" That's correct. That's why in my answer I said, "as long as you can ensure that your container runs with appropriate privileges". You didn't mention in your question that Fargate policy prevents privileged containers. In this case, you're probably out of luck.